# Making a custom Datagrid, how should I tackle this problem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently I am trying to create a table containing information of Players and Monsters. I do however notice that the way I am currently trying it in, seem to have some limits which do not satisfy my needs. I would like the table to look as the following:

[image]

I've created a `Player` class and a `Monster` class which contain the information of the entities. Features I would like for my table are the following:

- Any number of Player/Monsters
- Sort on INIT, which is randomly generated (1-20)
- Edit things on the fly (ObservableCollection<>?)
- Hover over underscored text to display information on the move (I've created a `NameValuePair` class with a `name` and `value`

I've tried to do things as the following, but it has this result.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGrid x:Name="creatureDatagrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="maxHP" Binding="{Binding MaxHp}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="AC" Binding="{Binding Ac}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="INIT" Binding="{Binding Dex}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="HP" Binding="{Binding Hp}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Senses" Binding="{Binding DmgRes}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Speed" Binding="{Binding Speed}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Senses" Binding="{Binding Senses}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Traits" Binding="{Binding Traits}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Actions" Binding="{Binding Actions}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Conditions" Binding="{Binding Conditions}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

As you can see, I struggle to convert the arrays into text, let alone convert the `NameValuePair` to `name` + hoverable `value`

What would be a way to create a table like the one in the example? Is this even possible for WPF, or am I better of which a different front-end framework? Thanks!

Some more information on my code/classes below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private readonly MonsterService _monsterService;
            private readonly DatabaseService _databaseService;
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                _monsterService = new MonsterService();
                _databaseService= new DatabaseService();
                foreach (var player in _databaseService.Players)
                {
                    creatureDatagrid.Items.Add(player);
                }
                _databaseService.DoStuff();
                foreach (var monster in _databaseService.ActiveMonsters)
                {
                    creatureDatagrid.Items.Add(monster);
                }
            }
        }
    
public partial class Player
    {
        public bool IsInParty { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Ac { get; set; }
        public string ArmorType { get; set; }
        public string[] Speed { get; set; }
        public int InitiativeBonus { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgVul { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgRes { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgImm { get; set; }
        public string[] CondImm { get; set; }
        public string[] Senses { get; set; }
        public string[] Languages { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] Conditions { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    
public partial class BaseMonster
    {
        public int BaseId { get; set; }
        public string BaseName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Alignment { get; set; }
        public int Ac { get; set; }
        public string ArmorType { get; set; }
        public int MaxHp { get; set; }
        public string HitDice { get; set; }
        public string[] Speed { get; set; }
        public int Str { get; set; }
        public int Dex { get; set; }
        public int Con { get; set; }
        public int Int { get; set; }
        public int Wis { get; set; }
        public int Cha { get; set; }
        public string[] SavThrProf { get; set; }
        public string[] SkillProf { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgVul { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgRes { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgImm { get; set; }
        public string[] CondImm { get; set; }
        public string[] Senses { get; set; }
        public string[] Languages { get; set; }
        public string Challenge { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] Traits { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] Actions { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] LegendaryActions { get; set; }
        public string LairActions { get; set; }
        public string RegionalEffects { get; set; }
    }
    
public partial class Monster : BaseMonster
    {
        public Monster(BaseMonster baseObject) 
        {
            this.BaseId = baseObject.BaseId;
            this.BaseName = baseObject.BaseName;
            this.Type = baseObject.Type;
            this.Alignment = baseObject.Alignment;
            this.Ac = baseObject.Ac;
            this.ArmorType = baseObject.ArmorType;
            this.MaxHp = baseObject.MaxHp;
            this.HitDice = baseObject.HitDice;
            this.Speed = baseObject.Speed;
            this.Str = baseObject.Str;
            this.Dex = baseObject.Dex;
            this.Con = baseObject.Con;
            this.Int = baseObject.Int;
            this.Wis = baseObject.Wis;
            this.Cha = baseObject.Cha;
            this.SavThrProf = baseObject.SavThrProf;
            this.SkillProf = baseObject.SkillProf;
            this.DmgVul = baseObject.DmgVul;
            this.DmgRes = baseObject.DmgRes;
            this.DmgImm = baseObject.DmgImm;
            this.CondImm = baseObject.CondImm;
            this.Senses = baseObject.Senses;
            this.Languages = baseObject.Languages;
            this.Challenge = baseObject.Challenge;
            this.Traits = baseObject.Traits;
            this.Actions = baseObject.Actions;
            this.LegendaryActions = baseObject.LegendaryActions;
            this.LairActions = baseObject.LairActions;
            this.RegionalEffects = baseObject.RegionalEffects;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public List<int> Damage { get; set; }
        public bool IsOverhealed => Hp > MaxHp;
        public bool IsBloody => Hp <= MaxHp / 2.0;
        public bool IsNearDeath => Hp <= MaxHp / 4.0;
        public bool IsDead => Hp <= 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Conditions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear why you think that an array like `string[] Speed` should be displayed as a single value in a cell. You may however display the first array element by `Binding="{Binding Speed[0]}"`.

Comment: *How* do you want to display the values in the array(s)?

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your response. I understand that adding [0] to it will show a single element, but I need them all.

Comment: @mm8 Thank you for your response. For example, the array could contain {30ft. , 50ft. swimming} (could also be more or less). I would like it to display it as "30 ft. - 50 ft. swimming" (as if you used .join(" - ") ).

Comment: Then bind to a property that returns `string.Join` instead of binding directly to the array. Or use a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding directly to a `string[]` property, you could add another `string` property to your `Player` class that returns the actual value that you want to display in the `DataGrid`, e.g.:

```
public string SensesDisplayValue => string.Join(",", Senses);
```

This effectively makes the `Player` class a kind of view model. If it's currently something else, you should replace it with a view model and add the view-friendly property to this one. Binding directly to some kind of entity or business object is usually not a good idea.

The other option is to use a [converter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/wpf-value-converters/) in the view to convert the array to a `string` value.

Comment: Ah, of course, that's a nice solution to it, thank you!

That answers most of my questions except one. Is it also possible to have a hoverable 'value' for each 'name' in my NameValuePairs?

Comment: You could replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and put whatever content you like in the `CellTemplate` and/or `CellEditTemplate` of the latter.